# sitefinity bootstrap Icons missing

Tags: sitefinity

In sitefinity how can I access the bootstrap Icons? Do I need to add a resource-package?

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" onclick='addRow(@item.Value,0)'></span>
```

Comment: do you load the bootstrap css file?

Comment: You mean ResourcePackages\Bootstrap\assets\dist\css\   File in this location!

Comment: @VeselinVasilev this is not working for me @Html.StyleSheet(Url.WidgetContent("~/ResourcePackages/Bootstrap4/assets/dist/css/main.css"), "head")

Comment: yes, that should include main.css file, which should contain the bootstrap classes. what is not working exactly? does the file loads successfully? can you check the contents of the file to make sure those classes are in it?

Comment: In the preview the icon will not display.

Comment: Thanks @VeselinVasilev its working now. Do you know anything about how to get the validation working ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65672858/sitefinity-validation-data-view